# Facebook Login Dialog Error on iOS

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, ios5.1

HEllo i am using old facebook sdk i think it is 3.0 and now i am going to update the app but during testing cant login on facebook now please let me know how to fix it.
Upgrading to 3.1 is too complex in the app for my app.

[image]

```
//Facebook Login  
        appDelegate.flag = 1;
        appDelegate.facebook.accessToken = nil;
        appDelegate.facebook.expirationDate = nil;

        NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookies];
        for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
            [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
        }

        NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"status_update", @"publish_stream", @"offline_access", @"publish_actions", @"read_stream", @"user_photos", @"photo_upload", @"photo_tag", nil];

        [appDelegate.facebook authorize:permissions];
```

}

Comment: You might want to at lease show us the code you use to login to facebook otherwise we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

At last issue solved that's all because of the parameters there is a single parameter which cause this issue i think facebook deprecate it or something else but issue solved :)

parameter is @"photo_tag"